# How do I prepend a Json object with ""Users" : " in Python?

Tags: python, json

I need to prepend a Json object with ""Users" : " but I can't figure out how to handle the ":". The closest I've gotten is getting the colon within the quotes and then it spits out an extra comma. Any ideas? So the issue is the colon sits in the quotes and it adds in a comma, which the api endpoint won't accept.

Here is what It should look like

```
**["users"  :** [{
    "email": "hallbeth@placeholder.email",
    "dataFields": {
        "favoriteTomatoe": "Green Zebra",
        "daysSinceLastOrder": "137",
        "city": "Lake Michaelberg",
        "firstName": "Richard",
        "zip": "58570",
        "lastName": "Tyler",
        "age": "50",
        "state": "UT",
        "totalTomatoOrders": "23",
        "streetAddress": "925 Holland Burgs Suite 652",
        "phoneNumber": "+67(4)7940410189",
        "gender": "male",
        "customMessageOne": "Esse magnam voluptatibus id ex ipsam assumenda excepturi tenetur."
    }
}]
```

And here is what the output looks like

```
**["users  :",** [{
    "email": "hallbeth@placeholder.email",
    "dataFields": {
        "favoriteTomatoe": "Green Zebra",
        "daysSinceLastOrder": "137",
        "city": "Lake Michaelberg",
        "firstName": "Richard",
        "zip": "58570",
        "lastName": "Tyler",
        "age": "50",
        "state": "UT",
        "totalTomatoOrders": "23",
        "streetAddress": "925 Holland Burgs Suite 652",
        "phoneNumber": "+67(4)7940410189",
        "gender": "male",
        "customMessageOne": "Esse magnam voluptatibus id ex ipsam assumenda excepturi tenetur."
    }
}]
```

Here is my code

```
 import requests
import json
import csv
import pdb

limit = 2
curVal = 0
user_list = []
user_list_2 = [
  ("users" + '  ' +  ':')]

with open('john.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_file = csv.reader(csv_file)

    next(csv_file)

    for line in csv_file :
        user_list.append(



            [{

            "email" : line[2],
            "dataFields" : {
                "firstName": line[0],
                "lastName" : line[1],
                "favoriteTomatoe" : line[3],
                "totalTomatoOrders" : line[4],
                "daysSinceLastOrder" : line[5],
                "zip" : line[6],
                "phoneNumber" : line[7],
                "age" : line[8],
                "streetAddress" : line[9],
                "city" : line[10],
                "state" : line[11],
                "customMessageOne" : line[12],
                "gender" : line[13]
                                }
            }])



    if curVal == limit:
        body = json.dumps(user_list_2 + user_list)
        print(body)
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"}
        res = requests.request("POST", 
            "https://api.iterable.com/api/users/bulkUpdate?apiKey="key", 
            headers=headers, data=body)

        curVal = 0
        user_list = []

        print(res.url + "\n\n" + str(res.status_code) + res.text) 

    else:

       curVal = curVal + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are multiple misunderstanding in your code.

First, each user is added to the `user_list` as a single-item-list containing one user-dictionary. You could simply skip the single-item-list level and simply append the dictionary:

```
user_list.append({
    "email" : line[2],
    "dataFields" : {
        "firstName": line[0],
        "lastName" : line[1],
        "favoriteTomatoe" : line[3],
        "totalTomatoOrders" : line[4],
        "daysSinceLastOrder" : line[5],
        "zip" : line[6],
        "phoneNumber" : line[7],
        "age" : line[8],
        "streetAddress" : line[9],
        "city" : line[10],
        "state" : line[11],
        "customMessageOne" : line[12],
        "gender" : line[13]
    }
})
```

Then you can consider a sort of mapping between Python and JSON types:

- Python list = JSON array
- Python dict = JSON object

So, the `user_list` can be interpreted as a JSON array and if you want it to be assigned as the `Users` property of a JSON object, you just have to assign the `user_list` as the value of a Python dict's `Users` key. Then passing the Python dict
to the `json.dumps` function should return the wanted JSON data:

```
body = json.dumps({'Users': user_list})
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks for your help!